# Email Validating regex to include period in the hostname compulsorily

Tags: regex, validation, email

I have the requirement to validate an email using the following conditions

1. If the email name (the part before the @ sign) entered starts with a period (.) the system should display a message error. Example:.mail@mail.com.
2. If the email name has characters different than the ones in the ASCII-US table, the system should display an error message.
3. If the email name ends with a period, the system should display an error message. Example: mail.@mail.com.
4. If the email name is longer than 64 characters, the system should display an error message.
5. If the complete email address is longer than 254 characters, the system should display an error message.
6. If the hostname (part after @ sign) does not starts with a letter or number (a-z and 0-9 characters), the system should display an error message.
7. If the host name should always have a period but shouldn't end with one.
8. If the host name is larger than 63 characters, the system should display an error message.

I am using this following regex which satisfies all of them except the (7) where there should be a 'period' compulsorily present in the hostname, it fails at emails like "abc@efg"

`` /^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/ ``

I need to keep this same regex as it satisfies all other conditions except the one i mentioned, what change can I make to satisfy that condition as well

Comment: When I have situations like this, I feel it might be better to break the rules into multiple regexes for future readability and maintenance.  When you see this regex a few years from now and you get a new requirement, would you be able to modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trial and errors I formulated the following regexp which takes care of all the above required criteria. Adding the answer here for anyone that stumbles across this in the future.

```
/^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$/
```